# MySQLi DATE_FORMAT not working at all

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

I have the following code, the database column has got the date and time, I want to search for records using just the data part. I have the following but I have a feeling it is very wrong.

```
$query = "SELECT id,uid,product,jpgID,saledatetime FROM sales WHERE printed = ? AND DATE_FORMAT('?', 'y/m/d') AS saledatetime";
```

**Edit:**
Working now, thanks:

```
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    //logged in
    $session_date = $_SESSION['session_date'];

    $query = "SELECT id,uid,product,jpgID,saledatetime 
                FROM sales 
             WHERE printed = ? 
                AND DATE_FORMAT(saledatetime , '%y/%m/%d') = ?";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        $printed = 0;
        $stmt->bind_param("is",$printed,$session_date);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        //Get result
        $stmt->bind_result($result_id,$result_uid,$result_product,$result_jpgID,$result_saledatetime);

        //Number of rows returned
        $count_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        echo $count_rows;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");  
}
```

Comment: See [examples here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) how to use `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE_FORMAT has [special syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). Query didn't compare formatted datetime to anything, so I presume it was meant to be like this?

```
SELECT id, uid, product, jpgID, saledatetime 
  FROM sales
 WHERE printed = ?
   AND DATE_FORMAT(saledatetime, '%y/%m/%d') = DATE_FORMAT(?, '%y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: Not getting an error now, but no rows are being returned, I have a column with the value 2014-02-05 17:59:25 under the saledatetime column, and that date that is being queried is the same date. @Michal Brašna

Comment: Then you can update the query to `DATE_FORMAT(saledatetime, '%y/%m/%d') = DATE_FORMAT(?, '%y/%m/%d')`