# Insert different date format with php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an upload script written in PHP which takes care of data from CSVs and inserts it into each specific table for each CSV that is uploaded.

I need to fix an issue with it not inserting data from a different date format correctly. It needs to cover all date formats and save it like YYYY-MM-DD (2016-09-27), except time.
It looks like this:

```
   Database table:  
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        USER VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        Date DATE,
        Time TIME

    PHP/MySQL
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (User, Date,Time) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $user, $date,$time);

        $user = $data_array[$i][0];
        $date = $data_array[$i][1];
        $time = $data_array[$i][2];

        $stmt->execute();
```

I've been reading about STR_TO_DATE but I'm not sure where I should use it in this case.

Comment: You can only insert `Y-m-d` type date into the database for the FORMAT DATE.

Comment: what exactly is datatype and value in $date = $data_array[$i][1];

Comment: "It needs to cover all date formats" - unless you can also specify some hints (e.g. by a LOCALE) this is impossible - e.g. there is no way to tell if 02/03/2016 is the 2nd of March or the 3rd of February, and that's before you consider the possibility of the year being represented by 2 digits or months represented by non-english words.

Comment: @symcbean Yeah, I realised that too after spending a couple of hours to fix this today.

Answer (score 0):

At first i noticed your define the vars after u use them with bind_param()
`$user $date $time`

Like this:

```
    $user = $data_array[$i][0];
    $date = $data_array[$i][1];
    $time = $data_array[$i][2];

    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $user, $date,$time);
```

Next:
You can use MySQL Date Format functions.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

With this function you can convert your string date into a valid MySQL date.

`VALUES(?,DATE_FORMAT('?','format'),?)`

Replace format with the format the data is in

Example from Manual: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');`

Comment: Should it be any quotation marks in the VALUES statement?

Comment: Like this, yes?
"INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (USER, Date,Time) VALUES (?,DATE_FORMAT('?','%Y-%m-%d'),?)");

It uploads the CSV but it wont create the table and insert the data :/

Comment: Since it uploads the CSV from an atmel based device it's a bit tricky to get the error printed on my screen. Maybe there is something in the logs.

Comment: I made a small manual upload form which I can choose which version of the upload script I want to use but I can't see any SQL-errors in the web browser? So it uploads with both but the newest version which should fix the date format doesn't insert the info into the table but it creates it.

Comment: I activated the PHP engines "display error"-function and got this.


`**Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /var/www/uploadfile_v3_test.php:84 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/uploadfile_v3_test.php(37): createTable('tabletest_1....') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/uploadfile_v3_test.php on line 84`

This corresponds to the `$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $date, $time, $bat);` part of the script. Maybe it gets confused by the DATE_FORMAT in the VALUES section?

Comment: Yeah, as I noted in my last sentence more or less :)

Comment: try adding in VALUES (?,?,?) this time swap with test strings and see if it works...

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21585243/6886291) Maybe this is what I need to do?

Comment: Im with you in your thinking about it but I'm looking at [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) and it seems to be how you do it?

Comment: **A step in the right direction!** Now I get this _After_ moving the vars definitions: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /var/www/uploadfile_v3_test.php on line 92`

But it's still not a fan of the **DATE_FORMAT** inside the VALUES

Comment: try this 
`$conn->prepare(sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (User, Date,Time) VALUES ("%s",DATE_FORMAT("%s","format"),"%s")', $table_name, $user, $date, $time));` remember to apply the format your data is in in `format` remove the bind_param() line, and make sure $user $date $time defined before this sprintf line

Comment: Thanks for all the help but since I don't have any reference to what date format my device uses it's no idea for a universal solution for now. I need to get my device to upload more data that I can use :)

Comment: can you do a echo $date and post result?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I still get errors from your solution :/ I need to find another solution that uses table joins so I can go around this problem until I get my hands on the electronics again. Thanks a lot for all you help!